# exim, variable string expansion

Tags: exim

How can I get the list of local domains from a forward file?

An example of `/etc/exim4/forwards`:

```
a@test.com: a@lala.com
# ignore this line
b@test.com: a@example.com
b@hugo.com: hugo@example.com
```

Here the string expansion (or what ever it's called *g*) should return `test.com : hugo.com`.

I assume it can be done with `readfile` and `map`, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that *almost* works the way you want it.  What this expansion does is:

1. Slurp in the file, using ; as the separator.
2. Exclude any lines with # in them (i.e. comments).
3. It *should* skip blank lines, but my regex isn't matching, it still includes those blank lines, so I just removed it and left the or{{}{}} block in there.
4. Extract the item before the : on each line, and extract the domain from that.
5. Mash it all up into the list.

I don't profess this to be exactly what you need, but it shows how the lists can be parsed and grep'd.

```
CentOS58[root@ivwm41 exim]# more test_list.cf 
a@test.com: a@lala.com
# ignore this line
b@test.com: a@example.com
b@hugo.com: hugo@example.com

CentOS58[root@ivwm41 exim]# exim -be '${reduce {<; ${readfile{/etc/exim/test_list.cf}{;}} } {} {${if  or{ {match{$item}{#}} {match{$item}{#}} } {$value} {$value:${sg {${extract{1}{:}{$item}}} {^.*@}{} }}}}}'
:test.com:test.com:hugo.com
```

If you spread out the expansion logically into its individual parts, it looks like this:

```
exim -be '${reduce {<; ${readfile{/etc/exim/test_list.cf}{;}} } 
             {}
             {${if or{ {match{$item}{#}} {match{$item}{#}} } 
                 {$value}
                 {$value:${sg{${extract{1}{:}{$item}}} {^.*@} {}}}}
             }
           }
         '
```

One thing that still needs to be fixed is that leading : should not be there.  I'm not 100% sure why it is there :-/ and I don't really have the time to delve any further into it.  The logic needs to be massaged a bit to catch whatever condition is causing that leading colon to appear and then the result should be a domain list that you can use as a condition.